# For loop includes zero

Tags: r

I have fixed my problem by telling my loop to ignore instances of 0. But I don't know why it wants to include them in the first place.

```
    P <- function(n) {
        if (n <= 1) {
        return (1)
        }
    
        s = 0
        for (i in 1 : n - 1) {
            if (i != 0) {
            s <- s + P(i) * P(n - i)
            }
        }
        return (s)
    }
    
    print (P(2))
```

It seems weird to include that in my loop, but without it I simply haven't been able to get the program to work. Not until I started putting in a trace to see what I was did I discover that i = 0. Did I write something wrong? I'm too new at R to even consider blaming this on the RGui that I'm using to run this, but I'm too old at programming to think anything else.

Comment: Would you please tell me what you are trying to achieve by this function and what is its main purpose?

Comment: Plus I would like to know whether the input is a single element or a vector.

Comment: Excellent question. This is a recurrence relation for calculating catalan numbers, specifically for the number of parenthesizations of n atoms.

Input is a single integer, n>=2

Comment: For instance, if you have 3 matrices, M1, M2 and M3, you can multiply them as (M1xM2)xM3 or M1(M2xM3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a precedent problem.  ":" takes precedent over "-"

Compare:

```
n<-5
c(1: n -1)
c(1:(n-1))
```

Comment: Sigh. Thank you. I feel dumb now. Ironic, since the knowledge has rendered me more intelligent.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you forgot a parenthesis, see [operator syntax & precedence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html) :

```
n <- 2
1: n-1
[1] 0 1

1:(n-1)
[1] 1
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. 1 minute earlier and you would have gotten the upvote.

Comment: @DaveX, actually I think I was 1 minute earlier, but it doesn't matter & the important thing is that you understood the pb, ;-)

Comment: Don't exaggerate, Waldi, you were only 59 seconds earlier ;-)